# Laravel Passport no funciona en AWS

Tags: laravel, aws, passport

estoy teniendo un problema… migre un sistema a AWS y ahora laravel/passport siempre responde `Unauthenticated` como si estuviese enviando mal el token… y el sistema lo estoy probando con postman…. y cuando accedo a las rutas que no ameritan autorizacion funcionan perfectamente, como lo es el registro (y me devuelve el access_token), pero a lo que lo coloco en el postman siempre me devuelve Unauthenticated, y en mi local funciona perfectamente.
Claro previo a eso aplico `php artisan passport:install --force` y despues `php atrasan passport:keys --force`